# BULK INSERT not inserting via JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, bulkinsert

I have a Java program that executes a `BULK INSERT` on SQL Server:

```
DELETE FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable];
BULK INSERT [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]
FROM '\\server\file.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

When I execute this SQL directly in SSMS, it inserts the data as expected.  But when I run through JDBC using `executeUpdate(sql);` the `DELETE` will work (so I know the connection is made and the statement is executed), but the `BULK INSERT` does nothing.  There's no error or SQL exception, it just doesn't insert any data.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Did you try two statements, a DELETE and a BULK INSERT?

Comment: Brilliant.  When I execute the two statements separately I get a SQLException: `Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened.`.  That's the issue, it was just being masked.